# Clothing falls off model?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am following along with an online tutorial to try and make a shirt, but instead of adhering to the 3d model, it falls right off and does not work.

[image]

Comment: The comments are not the place for sharing information essential to answer the question. These should be edited into the question body itself

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

### Activate Sewing

In the Cloth's Shape section, you didn't activate the Sewing option to enable the strings to be pulled.

[image]